# Distance between a box and another box?

Tags: tcolorbox, box

i am working on a file which is made up of the columns and each column contains boxes, but i have a problem with alignment or quite large vertical distance between the boxes and sometimes it jumps directly to the next column, here is the code and you please tell me what i can do to fix this problem.
thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,landscape,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{freemokmassoft}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox,varwidth,multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,hooks,skins,breakable}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{tbox}[1][]
{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,before title=\raggedright,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
%   enforce breakable,% use only breakable in the real world!
    pad at break=1mm, break at=-\baselineskip/0pt,
    boxrule=2pt,arc=1.5mm,
    colback=white,frame style={
        left color=white!50!gray,
        middle color=lightgray,
        right color=white!80!gray,
    },
    title=#1    
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\begin{tbox}
bla bla bla 
\end{tbox}

....

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any problem because there's only one box? Show a real code with "multiple boxes" and "large distance between boxes". Also with screenshot of output and explain what is wrong.

Comment: Large distances between boxes can usually be fixed (more or less) with \raggedbottom, which moves the large distances to the bottom  of the page.